# React-Native: Library not found iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, base64

I encounter a wired error. I am getting **Library not found for -lBase64**. I checked all the settings for iOS. I checked if Library is missing in **Link Binary With Libraries**, checked for twice entries in **Header Search Path** and **Library Search Path**. But it seems everything is working fine.

The error occurs only when I tried to build with **Release** mode.  You can check the attached screenshot for error.

[image]

Comment: Have check your derived data?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen Yes, I did it.